# Reading http packets under linux

Tags: http, packet-sniffers, rfc2616

I'm reading RFC 2616 and I would like to see all http packets. Which tool is the best for this?

Comment: Fairly open question - fairly open recommendation :-) try wireshark. Or just use an HTTP proxy, maybe that's enough for your needs.

Comment: What @home says (or tcpdump to capture a stream and then wireshark to search, filter and prettyprint) but many of the interesting aspects of the protocol can already be studied with Firebug or Chrome's developer tools.  I would use a high level tool like firebug to look at the communication from a high level, and occasionally look what's going on in the deeper layers with wireshark.

Comment: home, @fvu you are right, but I'm looking for tools which gives me plain http headers without filtering and so on. I may want to use also curl, thus chrome and ff extensions are not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try htracr - 
  https://github.com/mnot/htracr/

BTW, RFC2616 will soon be superceded; see
  http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/wiki